# Best analysis for checking the relationship between two variables when one of them have repeated values

Tags: regression, anova, biostatistics, kruskal-wallis-test, climate

I have a dataset with different measures of plants (height, size of leafs, etc.) in 5 localities. I want to check if there is a relationship between those variables with temperature and precipitation. However, the only climate data that I have is in the form of rasters at a very gross resolution, so each locality has only one value for those climatic variables.

So If I want to check the relationship of plants height with those two climatic variables, I have the problem that, for example, temperature is repeated for all the plants in locality 1, and another temperature value is repeated for all the plants in locality 2, etc. And the same for precipitation. So I don't know if performing directly a Spearman correlation or a linear model with that data would be correct. Maybe would be more correct to perform an ANOVA/Kruskal Wallis comparison? What analysis do you reccomend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question comes down to details of your data structure.

If you only have 1 temperature value for *all* observations at each locality, then you will have a strict dependence between temperature and locality. You can model either temperature or locality, but not both. If you think that the localities are equivalent except for temperature, precipitation, etc. then you could build a model of associations of outcome(s) with those variables that doesn't include locality as a fixed predictor.

If you have multiple observations over time and thus you have multiple temperature and precipitation values within each of the localities, then there should be no problem at all. There might be a problem if, for some reason, you still end up with a strict linear dependence between the localities and some combination of predictor values.

The alternatives that you suggest won't help with the problem that concerns you. Correlations on their own can be very misleading, as they ignore the influences of other outcome-associated predictors. ANOVA is just a name for a particular type of regression model of categorical predictors, but you are interested in continuous predictors. Multiple regression, ideally in a way that takes the multiple outcome types into account, is a good choice.